# Partially hidden inheritance tree

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class tree as such:

```
class A;
class B : public A;
```

I then want to create a class which is derived from class B. But I want that derivation to be hidden from outside members as well as anyone else that inherits from class C

```
class C : private B;

void test() {
    C c;
    B *b = &c; // compiler error: B in C is private and is therefore not type compatible. This is desired.
}
```

However, I also want to reveal the inheritance of class A. Hiding class B in this case also hides class A.

```
void test2() {
    C c;
    A *a = &c; // Compiler error: A is only accessible through B which is not possible with a private inheritance of B. This is not desired; this conversion should be possible.
}
```

I could inherit from A again, but that would obviously create duplicate member variables if A has any. I could create a virtual inheritance of class A, however I don't feel it would have the exact effect I desire since that would affect the entire tree rather than this segment (right?)

I suppose the obvious solution would be to create a typecasting member function:

```
class C : private B {
    A * turn_into_A() {
        // Since B is an A and we are still in the scope of C, this will succeed
        return this;
    }
};
```

However, I'd prefer to avoid explicit typecasts such as that case,

Any sane person might tell me I'm doing this wrong. They'd probably be right. But I would like to know simply for knowledge's sake: is there a way to do this without virtual inheritance or an explicit member function's typecast?

Comment: @milleniumbug Ha, wrong question. Apoligies.

Comment: Luckily, you left open the possibility of a free friend function doing the type cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution:

```
class A {
public:
    void somethingA() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
 };
class B :
    public A {
public:
    void somethingB() {
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
};
class C :
    private B {
public:
using B::A; // While B is private (and hidden), this exposes access to B::A
    void somethingC() {
        std::cout << "c" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C c;
    B* b = &c; // Compiler error: cannot convert because B is private (desired)
    A* a = &c; // Okay! (required)
    c.somethingC();
    c.somethingB(); // Compiler error: private. (desired)
    c.somethingA(); // Compiler error: A is exposed, but not A's members. This can be solved by adding 'using B::A::somethingA()' in class declaration (undesired but acceptable in my situation)
    a->somethingA(); // Okay! (of course)
}
```

It's not perfect in that it only exposes C to be able to be converted to A (which for my purposes is what I'll end up doing anyway, so that's fine). However it doesn't directly expose the members of A to allow C to be used as-an-A, eg you cannot call c::somethingA() unless you specifically also expose B::A::somethingA.

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance depicts a IS-A relationship. So, in your object model, B IS-A A, C IS-A B. So, why don't you use

```
class C : public B { ...};
```

So that you may view a C object as a B object as well as an A object as need be. Hope that helps.

Comment: because he wants to inherit privately after B?

Comment: @zoska yes, but that's contradicting, while privately inheriting you cannot use it viewed as a superclass object. Otherwise, friend may help.

Comment: Because I specifically do not want it to show that it's a B. The idea I'm trying to implement is that class B and C are *not* actually related... they just happen to share a lot of the same functionality. So to reduce code duplication, having one or the other inherit from the other to be able to re-use code is beneficial. However, they are NOT related and therefore should not be used in any interchangeable fashion.

Comment: Well then you cannot view a C as a B.